# Prevent browser to disclose user input

Tags: security

Is it possible to load a web page and then reliably and permanently prevent the browser (and the potentially hostile web page) to disclose any user input made on that page?
Cross browser?

Use case would be an online utility exposing some service on personal information. This utility will not need to make any server requests after it is loaded.

The following procedure explains the question, but is probably not sufficient nor efficient:

1. Load web page
2. Go offline
3. Interact with the web page
4. Close the page
5. Remove cookies
6. Clear web storage
7. Go online

Comment: Yes, simply remove the ethernet cable from the rear of your computer during steps 3 through 6...

Comment: or....Open the browser in private mode. usually Ctrl + Shift + P does it.

Comment: @Shoban You mean load in private mode, go offline, then shut down the browser?